# PHP ODBC PDO driver for Microsoft SQL Server returning empty array or false

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo

I have this code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('odbc:MSSQLServer', 'user', 'pass');

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        

var_dump($result);
```

If:

```
$sql = "select seri_cdser from tsica_alun_matr";
```

The output is:

```
array(1) {
    ["seri_cdser"]=>
    string(4) "3EMM"
}
```

But if:

```
$sql = "select * from tsica_alun_matr";
```

The output is:

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Numeric value out of range (SQLFetchScroll[0] at /usr/local/src/PDO_ODBC/odbc_stmt.c:372)
```

Sometimes an empty array is returned too, apparently the driver is instable.

The table `tsica_alun_matr` has 13 columns.

Someone knows if it is a bug with PDO driver for MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a comment in PHP docs:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php

That says:

> 1. The second error I had was:
>
> > > > Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 0 [Microsoft][SQL Native
> > > >         Client]Numeric value out of range (SQLFetchScroll[0] at
> > > >         ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:372)' in (YOUR_TRACE_HERE) <<< Another
> > > >         meaningless error "Numeric value out of range"... 
> > > >         
> > > >         -> I was actually returning a date datatype (datetime or smalldatetime) "as is", that is, without converting it to varchar
> > > >         before including it in the result set... I don't know if PDO is
> > > >         responsible for converting it to a PHP datatype, but it doesn't.
> > > >         Convert it before it reaches PHP.

So, as exist `datetime` and `smalldate` fields i have changed my PDO query as below, converting `datetime` and `smalldatetime` to `varchar`. [This page](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) helps to choose the best converstion format.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("
    select
        alun_cdal,
        seri_cdser,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), matp_dat_Mat, 121) as matp_dat_Mat,
        alun_nmal,
        alun_sexo,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), alun_dnsc, 121) as alun_dnsc
    from 
        tsica_alun_matr");
```

Now my code is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

My connection string looks different when using PDO with MSSQL. Not sure if this will help but this is how I do it:

```
$c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=x.x.x.x;Database=db_name", "username", "password");
```

This might help with debugging too:

```
$c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? I am using an ODBC driver on Linux to connect to MS SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for your help, i found the solution and posted as answer!